# How to create raster from table containing cell values in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, raster, postgresql

I am having a table with integer values. These values are in between 0 and 2. I want to create a raster out of that table with integers as cell values. Or else how to create polygons out of that table with each polygon consisting of same integer value.

That table is not geometry. So, is it possible to check whether the particular pixel value is present in the raster or not. If I can get the this I can use ST_SetValues for assigning new pixel value.

Comment: It isn't entirely clear how you are mapping your integer values to rasters. Where are the x and y values coming from? Are you using interpolation?